# default page in vesta cpanel using wordpress is not working

Tags: wordpress, vesta

I install wordpress in vesta cpanel using this tutorial [How to install WordPress in Vesta Control Panel](http://mgeeky.com/install-wordpress-vesta-control-panel/%20%22%22)

but the default page is still the previous page. i cant see the install page. i upload the files in `/home/admin/web/myhost.com/public_html`

Comment: with some of the hosting companies you have to delete the existing default file. check for an index.html or index.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem a while back and I've just installed a new server with vesta and I'm searching for the solution again...

You need to set the NGINX default file which is set to index.html but not index.php